# How to get back my windows and windows loader?

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, uefi, bios

I installed a Linux (Fedora) as second OS. I did like that so many times but with other distros. After installing I tried to boot in my first OS (Windows 11), but in a grub I didn't see her. I tried to re-install my Windows, when I went to BIOS, I couldn't boot in my flash drive and all UEFI ways to boot are gone. Now I'm sitting without my Windows and I can't install something else. Also I tried to update the grub, add some parameters in a config file and etc. If I try to boot in the windows (in one of my pictures you can see), then it boots me in the grub and after that I can't load my distro.

Before installing Fedora, every time when I got any error from installer, I was trying to boot through selecting a EFI file and it always worked - I tried this way to solve the problem and it's doesn't work.

All images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIcKV.jpg

P.s. I know my English is not very well, but I'm learning him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that you did not boot the Fedora installer in UEFI mode, but in legacy BIOS mode. It has written a legacy BIOS-style MBR on your disk, and apparently your system firmware (currently?) prefers booting in legacy mode over UEFI mode. If it sees a disk that is bootable in both modes, it will pick the legacy mode, which is the wrong choice for your existing Windows 11 installation.

If your BIOS settings include an option to "boot in UEFI mode only", selecting that might be the easiest way to solve this problem and avoid it happening again in the future.

If there is no such option, there are two ways to fix it.

One way would be to *destroy the MBR boot code* so the system firmware will have no choice but to boot in UEFI mode. You could do that by booting Linux from some external live media, and writing zeroes to the first 440 bytes of the Master Boot Record of the hard disk, like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1
```

If you do this, be **very careful**: any mistakes in this command could cause further destruction. Also, when booting from external media, the system disk might get a different device name, so make sure you're targeting the correct disk and adjust the `/dev/sda` part of the command if needed.

(Since your disk is partitioned using GPT partitioning, the contents of MBR should not be important at all, but it's best to not overwrite the part after the first 440 bytes, just to be safe)

The other way would be to boot from the Windows installation media (important: in UEFI mode!) and use its "repair boot" function.

You might want to delete the `/dev/sda7` partition, as it contains a legacy BIOS version of GRUB which should become useless when Fedora is properly installed in UEFI mode.

---

To fix your existing Fedora installation, you could boot from an external live Linux media, mount the root filesystem of your Fedora installation, chroot into it, then remove the `grub2-pc-<version number>.x86_64.rpm` package (the version of GRUB for booting in legacy BIOS style) and install `grub2-efi-<version number>.x86_64.rpm` instead. To be compatible with Secure Boot, you probably should also install the `shim-<version number>.x86_64.rpm` package. Then you should mount the EFI system partition `/dev/sda1` at `/boot/efi`, and run `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda` to explicitly install a UEFI version of GRUB.

If your live media failed to boot in UEFI mode, `grub2-install` might display an error message, because it won't be able to access UEFI boot variables. But it should still have installed the UEFI GRUB, so you should then be able to boot by selecting `Boot from EFI File` and selecting `\EFI\Fedora\shimx64.efi` (Secure Boot-compatible) or `\EFI\Fedora\grubx64.efi` (with Secure Boot disabled).

Once you have the system booted to Fedora in UEFI mode, you could just re-run `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda` to create the necessary UEFI boot variable, or install the `efibootmgr` package and use it to configure the UEFI boot variables yourself.